# VB.net nullreferenceexception was unhandled in dr.read

Tags: sql, vb.net, nullreferenceexception

So i was working on the login portion on my library using the following code:

```
 While dr.Read
        If txtPassword.Text = dr("LibrarianPassword") And txtUserName.Text = dr("LibrarianID") Then
            main.Show()
        Else
            MsgBox("Username and password mismatch!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Login error")
        End If
    End While
```

the while dr.read line gives me a nullreferenceexception was unhandled error the moment the compiler evaluates the main.show line (main portion of my system is shown) and i didn't get that error the last time I was working on it...

Comment: Has 'main' been instantiated? Are you sure it is that line that is erroring. Have you tried running in debug mode? You also understand that since its in a while loop there's the possibility that if the dr dataset has more than one record it will loop many times potentially showing the mistmatch warning over and over. If dr() only has one record - when why a while loop? Perhaps list more of your code?

Comment: Side note: you really ought to learn about proper ways of performing authentication. Storing the password in *plain* text in the database is a very poor idea.

Comment: we're only at the basic level of database management so we're not tackling software security yet. we're more on processing and database design as of the moment.

Comment: @robnick yes it's been instantiated and i've run this at debug mode multiple times making minor adjustments that i thought would help cure the error.

Answer (score 0):

**Check the value first if it is null, Null value cannot be compare with other data types.**

```
While dr.Read
        If txtPassword.Text = IIf(IsDBNull( dr("LibrarianPassword")), "",  dr("LibrarianPassword")) And txtUserName.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dr("LibrarianID")), "", dr("LibrarianID")) Then
            main.Show()
        Else
            MsgBox("Username and password mismatch!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Login error")
        End If
End While
```

Comment: tried that and that same error pops up still... Now that i think about it, i have come across this same error once before when i was making a point of sales system for our database management class before. The only option i could think of was to rebuild the entire system, which did work.

thanks very much for your reply though.

Comment: So i ended up rebuilding the system i was making.. and that same error popped up. but this time i had this code in my main form:

Answer (score 0):

so i ended up rebuilding the system.. got that same error but this time I removed these lines of code from my main form:

```
 Private Sub frmLibSystemMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    open_con()

    sqlSearch = "select * from tblBooks"

    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlSearch, con)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    While dr.Read
        lsvBooks.Items.Add(dr("AccessionNumber"))
        lsvBooks.Items(lsvBooks.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr("BookCode"))
        lsvBooks.Items(lsvBooks.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr("Title"))
        lsvBooks.Items(lsvBooks.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr("Author"))
        lsvBooks.Items(lsvBooks.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr("Category"))
        lsvBooks.Items(lsvBooks.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr("Publisher"))
        lsvBooks.Items(lsvBooks.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr("PublicationYear"))
        lsvBooks.Items(lsvBooks.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr("Edition"))
        lsvBooks.Items(lsvBooks.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr("NumPages"))
        lsvBooks.Items(lsvBooks.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr("CopiesAvailable"))
    End While

    dr.Close()
    dr = Nothing
    cmd = Nothing
    sqlSearch = Nothing
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

and to my surprise, it solved the problem. I don't know how or why it solved the problem but it just did. But if i remove that from my main how will i load the list of books now..